# How to draw a linear plot with matplotlib using the categorical sklearn boston housing dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm a beginner in data science and I'm trying to draw a linear plot with matplotlib (and other packages like pandas and numpy) with the boston dataset.  I am asked to draw it from the [0,1] interval.  I am asked to plot the price of homes (`TARGET`, which is the y-axis) against the crime rate in the area (`CRIM`, which is the x axis).  My goal is to use Matplotlib's histogram but I couldn't find how to do that for a categorical dataset like this.  By now, this is the code I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston

boston = load_boston()

dataFrame_x = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns = boston.feature_names)
dataFrame_y = pd.DataFrame(boston.target)

dataFrame_x.describe()
```

And this is the data description (it looks too crummy on SO. I apologize for that):

```
    CRIM    ZN  INDUS   CHAS    NOX RM  AGE DIS RAD TAX PTRATIO B   LSTAT
count   506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000  506.000000
mean    3.613524    11.363636   11.136779   0.069170    0.554695    6.284634    68.574901   3.795043    9.549407    408.237154  18.455534   356.674032  12.653063
std 8.601545    23.322453   6.860353    0.253994    0.115878    0.702617    28.148861   2.105710    8.707259    168.537116  2.164946    91.294864   7.141062
min 0.006320    0.000000    0.460000    0.000000    0.385000    3.561000    2.900000    1.129600    1.000000    187.000000  12.600000   0.320000    1.730000
25% 0.082045    0.000000    5.190000    0.000000    0.449000    5.885500    45.025000   2.100175    4.000000    279.000000  17.400000   375.377500  6.950000
50% 0.256510    0.000000    9.690000    0.000000    0.538000    6.208500    77.500000   3.207450    5.000000    330.000000  19.050000   391.440000  11.360000
75% 3.677083    12.500000   18.100000   0.000000    0.624000    6.623500    94.075000   5.188425    24.000000   666.000000  20.200000   396.225000  16.955000
max 88.976200   100.000000  27.740000   1.000000    0.871000    8.780000    100.000000  12.126500   24.000000   711.000000  22.000000   396.900000  37.970000
```

Comment: You need to provide more details to the reader. What column do you want to plot against which column. How should your expected histogram look like? There are so many columns in the dataset. How would the reader know without you telling them, what to plot?

Comment: I know there are many columns.  That's what I was talking about.  I've never plotted a categorical dataset.  Do I just select 2 columns to plot?

Comment: Since you are working with the dataset, it is you who is expected to know what to plot and visualize. What exactly is your intention behind this project?

Comment: Its not really a project.  I am asked to create a simple plot with the data set.

Comment: "Simple plot with the dataset" is too vague a term. I would suggest to go through the Boston Dataset related websites to know what you should plot.

Comment: Okay so I've figured it out.  I want to plot the price 'TARGET' against the crime rate 'CRIM'.

Comment: So the x-axis will be CRIM and y-axis TARGET? And you want to just plot them? Or plot a linear fit through them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your comments, following is the way to perform linear fit to the data. Since you want to plot `CRIM` versus `Target` for region 0 to 1, you use indexing to get the `CRIM` values from the DataFrame and then perform a linear regression on the values.

```
xdata = dataFrame_x['CRIM'][dataFrame_x['CRIM'] < 1].values
ydata = dataFrame_y[dataFrame_x['CRIM'] < 1].values.flatten()

xmesh = np.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata), 50)

fit = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 1))

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'bo', label='Data')
plt.plot(xmesh, fit(xmesh), '-b', label='Fit')
plt.legend(fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('CRIM', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('Target',fontsize=18)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've accepted and upvoted your answer.  If you think that this was a well asked question, could you give me an upvote as well?

Comment: I did. Thanks. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to plot two continuous variables. Hence relationship would be best explained by the scatter plot or similar visualization. Here, I have tried to plot Hexagonal binning of the scatter plot. You can try other versions, using the following [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn.jointplot). Individual variable histograms are shown are on the extremes.

```
import seaborn as sns

filter_cdtn = dataFrame_x['CRIM'] < 1

sns.jointplot(x=dataFrame_x.loc[filter_cdtn,'CRIM'], 
              y=boston.target[filter_cdtn], 
              kind="hex").set_axis_labels("CRIM", "Target")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Questions.
1.  What is the purpose of `filter_cdtn = dataFrame_x['CRIM'] < 1` and why is it less than 1?
2.  What does this mean `y=boston.target[filter_cdtn]` if `filter_cdtn` represents `CRIM`?

Comment: 1.  since you have mentioned in your question `draw it from the [0,1] interval`, I have filtered the records based on this condition. 2. same filtering of records is applied on `y` as well. You can remove the filter_cdtn, if its not required for you.